# Solve ${\rm BinomialDistribution}(x;\,n_1,\,p_1) = {\rm BinomialDistribution}(a-x;\,n_2,\,p_2)$ in terms of $x$

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm totally a novice with Wolfram software, so please forgive me if the question is nonsense.

I want to solve the following equation in terms of $x$:

$\quad \quad {\rm BinomialDistribution}(x;\,n_1,\,p_1) = {\rm BinomialDistribution}(a-x;\,n_2,\,p_2)$

Of course,

$\quad \quad {\rm BinomialDistribution}(x;\,n,\,p) = \binom{n}{p}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$

I tried the following statement on Wolfram|Alpha, but nothing shown:

```
Solve[
  Binomial[b, x] a^x (1-a)^(b-x) - Binomial[e, d-x] c^(d-x) (1-c)^(e-(d-x)) == 0, 
  x]
```

although the following one seems to [show a solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[%20a%5Ex%20(1-a)%5E(b-x)%20==%20c%5E(d-x)%20(1-c)%5E(e-(d-x)),%20x]):

```
Solve[a^x (1-a)^(b-x) == c^(d-x) (1-c)^(e-(d-x)), x].
```

### Update

I replaced binomial coefficient with the Gamma function and tried the following:

```
(Gamma[1+b]/(Gamma[1+x] Gamma[1-x+b])) a^x (1-a)^(b-x) - 
  (Gamma[1+e]/(Gamma[1+d-x] Gamma[1-(d-x)+e])) c^(d-x) (1-c)^(e-(d-x))
```

The above [shows a reasonable result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(Gamma(1%20b)/(Gamma(1%20x)%20Gamma(1-x%20b)))%20a%5Ex%20(1-a)%5E(b-x)%20-%20(Gamma(1%20e)/(Gamma(1%20d-x)%20Gamma(1-(d-x)%20e)))%20c%5E(d-x)%20(1-c)%5E(e-(d-x))%20), but [below show still nothing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[%20(Gamma(1%20b)/(Gamma(1%20x)%20Gamma(1-x%20b)))%20a%5Ex%20(1-a)%5E(b-x)%20-%20(Gamma(1%20e)/(Gamma(1%20d-x)%20Gamma(1-(d-x)%20e)))%20c%5E(d-x)%20(1-c)%5E(e-(d-x))%20==%200,%20x]).

```
Solve[
  (Gamma[1+b]/(Gamma[1+x] Gamma[1-x+b])) a^x (1-a)^(b-x) - 
    (Gamma[1+e]/(Gamma[1+d-x] Gamma[1-(d-x)+e])) c^(d-x) (1-c)^(e-(d-x)) == 0, 
  x]
```

Comment: The syntax is incorrect.  Read the documentation for `Solve`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you, I checked this (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and update the statement to `solve[ binomial(b,x) a^x (1-a)^(b-x) - binomial(e,d-x) c^(d-x) (1-c)^(e-(d-x)) == 0 , x]`.  However, nothing changed.

Comment: The first letter of `Solve`, and all Mathematica functions (such as `Binomial`), is capitalized. The argument list of `Binomial` should be enclosed in `[  ]`. You really need to read the documentation for all functions you use.  Also, as you improve your syntax, please edit your question to show your most current version.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thanks, and I updated my question. But the point you mentioned does not change the result.

Comment: I presume that you really mean, `Solve[(Gamma[1 + b]/(Gamma[1 + x] Gamma[1 - x + b])) a^x (1 - a)^(b - x) - (Gamma[1 + e]/(Gamma[1 + d - x] Gamma[1 - (d - x) + e])) c^(d - x) (1 - c)^(e - (d - x)) == 0, x]` instead of what you have in the question.  If so, you probably received the message, `Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>`, which means just what it says.  Not all equations can be solved symbolically.  You may wish to give numerical values to your constants and use `NSolve` to obtain a numerical answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I got `NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.` with `NSolve`. I just hope to get approximate solution represented with `(a,b,c,d,e)`. Is it impossible with mathematica?

Comment: In that case, try `FindRoot`.  To do so, you need to provide an initial guess.

Comment: @bbgodfrey `FindRoot[(Gamma[1 + b]/(Gamma[1 + x] 
Gamma[1 - x + b])) a^x (1 - a)^(b - x) - (Gamma[1 + e]/(Gamma[1 + d - x]
 Gamma[1 - (d - x) + e])) c^(d - x) (1 - c)^(e - (d - x)) == 0, {x, 0}]` returns `General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::nlnum will be suppressed during this calculation.`  Here is the image: http://imgur.com/wEAFFlK

Comment: I continue to urge you to provide your code in the question.  Your last comment provides only a part of the code, because it leaves several symbols undefined.  Without that information, readers cannot be of assistance to you.  Moreover, images are no substitute for code.  Finally, I point out that the first error message is the one that matters most.

Comment: Your definition (image)  is incorrect (I assume a typo, surely you meant  nCx, not nCp). In any case, as hinted, you'll not get a symbolic solution to this, at best you can use numerical methods. Perhaps better to ask on *Math.Stackexchange.Com* why this is so, you'll have a larger audience of patient combinatorists there...

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, before going into Detail, it is a good idea to get first an overview over the situation, preferrably graphical.
You could proceed like this.

The problem can be formulated as follows: find the zeroes in `x` of the function

$$f = p^x \binom{n}{x} (1-p)^{n-x}-q^x \binom{m}{a-x} (1-q)^{m-(a-x)}$$

In Mathematica define `f` as

```
f[n_, p_, m_, q_, a_, x_] := 
 Binomial[n, x] p^x (1 - p)^(n - x) - 
  Binomial[m, a - x] q^(a - x ) (1 - q)^(m - (a - x))
```

Since there are 5 parameters in the problem we use apropriate random values.

The parameter `a` is assumed to be real and uniformly distributed between -1 and +1

```
ra := RandomReal[{-1, 1}]
```

For `p` and `q` we take real numbers uniformly distributed between 0 and +1

```
rp := RandomReal[{0, 1}]
```

and `n` and `m` are integers, assumed here between 0 and, say, 5

```
ri := RandomInteger[{0, 5}]
```

Now let's call the function with an set of randomly chosen parameters and make a plot.

A random set of parameters (with `x` appended to simplify what folllows) is

```
pars = {ri, rp, ri, rp, ra, x}

(*
Out[78]= {2, 0.332205, 0, 0.157944, -0.15634, x}
*)
```

The function `f` with these parameters is given by

```
fr = f @@ pars

(*
Out[79]= -0.157944^(-0.15634 - x) 0.842056^(0.15634 + x) Binomial[0, -0.15634 - x] + 
 0.332205^x 0.667795^(2 - x) Binomial[2, x]
*)
```

Plotting it gives

```
Plot[fr, {x, -5, 5}]
(* 150601_plot_fBinom1.jpg *)
```

[image]

You should repeat the next lines in order to see which type of zeroes might arise

```
pars = {ri, rp, ri, rp, ra, x}
Plot[fr = f @@ pars, {x, -5, 5}]
(* 150601_plot _fBinom2.jpg *)

(*
{5, 0.554662, 1, 0.773222, 0.437614, x}
*)
```

[image]

In many cases there are infinitely many zeroes, in others only a few. For a given set of parameters you can then use `FindRoot[]` in the vicinity of a root you see in the graph.

In order to get more precise information you need to specify the parameter ranges, and - even better - pose the original problem.